# Different size for lines in ggplot2's geom_line

Tags: r, ggplot2, line-plot

Is it possible to have different sized (i.e. thick) lines drawn with `geom_line`?

The size parameters is the same for all lines, irrespective of the group:

```
bp <- ggplot(data=diamonds, aes(x=cut, y=depth)) +
  geom_line(aes(color=cut), size=1)
```

However, I want the thickness of the lines to reflect their relative importance measured as number of observations:

```
relative_size <- table(diamonds$cut)/nrow(diamonds)
bp <- ggplot(data=diamonds, aes(x=cut, y=depth)) +
  geom_line(aes(color=cut), size=cut)
bp
# Error: Incompatible lengths for set aesthetics: size
```

Interestingly, `geom_line(..., size=cut)` works but not as expected, since it doesn't alter line size at all.

Comment: You could put `size=....` inside the `aes`.

Comment: @Heroka, do you want to provide an answer such that I can accept it?

Comment: @MERose LyzandeR already provided an answer, you can accept that one.

Comment: That's not the same and much more complicated.

Comment: Well, @LyzandeR gave an answer that's exactly as you asked ("thickness to reflect relative importance"). My suggestion does not warrant a standalone answer anyway.

Comment: Thanks @Heroka very kind of you :). @MERose, you need to be careful when you use a variable that is categorical as a size measure. If `cut` were a character field the graph would look problematic. It makes sense (at least to me) when you want the relative difference to be depicted as size to provide a numeric field so that the relative difference can be calculated. Providing a factor (as in this occasion) works well because factors are integers internally.

Answer (score 5):

In order to do this you need to create a new variable for `relative_size` that will be of the same length as the rows of the data.frame and add it to your data.frame. In order to do this, you could do:

```
#convert relative_size to a data.frame
diams <- diamonds
relative_size <- as.data.frame(table(diamonds$cut)/nrow(diamonds))

#merge it to the diams data.frame so that it has the same length
diams <- merge(diams, relative_size, by.x='cut', by.y='Var1', all.x=TRUE)
```

---

Note that the above can be replaced by code using `dplyr`:

```
diamonds %>% group_by(cut) %>% mutate(size = length(cut) / nrow(diamonds))
```

---

Then you need to follow @Heroka 's advice and use size inside of `aes` with your newly created column in your diams data.frame:

```
bp <- ggplot(data=diams, aes(x=cut, y=depth)) +
  geom_line(aes(color=cut, size=Freq))
bp
```

And it works:

[image]

Comment: Added some `dplyr` code that simplifies your calls to `table` and then `merge`.

Comment: Where is `Freq` initialized?

Comment: @Kulluk007 It is a column in `relative_size`. If you type `as.data.frame.table` on your console, you will see that the function creates a data.frame and gives the name Freq to the second column.